# Given a condition, modify values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains codes with one letter and three digits maximum, ex: A478.
Some codes only have one or two digits, but I need to put a point before all values that have three digits, to transform them in the form:

A213 to A21.3

In short, I need to transform the df in this way:

```py
id code1 code2 code3 code4
0  A099  B25   A022  NaN
1  B21   J2    Z23   H355
2  C212 C03  NaN   NaN
```

to

```py
id code1 code2 code3 code4
0  A09.9 B25   A02.2 NaN
1  B21   J2    Z23   H35.5
2  C21.2 C03  NaN   NaN
```

I've tried to use something like this, but i get an invalid syntax, so I don't know how to evaluate the condition of it happening only if it has three digits (or 4 str).

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:3]+'.'+x.str[3:] if len(x) == 4)
```

Comment: change your `lambda` to `lambda x: np.where(x.str.len(), x.str[:3]+'.'+x.str[3:], x)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all the 'code' columns, map a lambda with [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to the elements inserting the dot if the element is not NaN and its length is 4:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(lambda x: x[:3]+'.'+x[3:] if not pd.isna(x) and len(x) == 4 else x)
```

Result:

```
   id  code1 code2  code3  code4
0   0  A09.9   B25  A02.2    NaN
1   1    B21    J2    Z23  H35.5
2   2  C21.2   C03    NaN    NaN
```

PS: If `id` is the index you can `df.applymap()` directly on the whole dataframe.

Comment: Nice Solution @Stef, Would you mind adding little explanation so it can benefit Posterity +1

Comment: @KarnKumar I added some explanations as per your request.

Comment: Thanks @Stef.. that will add more value :-), appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas str function's replace method with regex like this

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"(.)(\d{2})(\d)",r"\1\2.\3"))
```

**Full Working Code**

```py
import numpy as np

arr=[]
for i in range(5):
    z = zip(np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C"], 3), np.random.choice(150, 3))
    arr.append([np.nan if np.random.rand()<.2 else f"{a}{b}" for a, b in z])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["code_1", "code_2", "code_3"])
display("df: ", df)
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"(.)(\d{2})(\d)",r"\1\2.\3"))
```

**Output**

```
'df: '
code_1  code_2  code_3
0   NaN NaN C102
1   B19 NaN B65
2   C106    A82 A138
3   C109    A74 C15
4   C117    B101    A90


code_1  code_2  code_3
0   NaN NaN C10.2
1   B19 NaN B65
2   C10.6   A82 A13.8
3   C10.9   A74 C15
4   C11.7   B10.1   A90
```